# FAB Menu Button with angular2-mdl

Tags: angular, material-design-lite, angular2-mdl

I'm building an Angular 2 app with angular2-mdl. I've add a FAB button to my page but can't find anywhere in the docs, angular2-mdl or MDL, information on how to add a FAB menu ([see image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUsJZ.png).

Is there a way todo this with angular2-mdl or MDL? I've see it done in many apps.

Here is my button code so far:

```
<button (click)="editUserDialog.show()" mdl-button  mdl-button-type="fab" mdl-colored="accent" mdl-ripple>
    <mdl-icon>add</mdl-icon>
</button>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I built a FAB menu with angular2-mdl using the popover menu from `@angular2-mdl/popover` and the fab-button from `@angular2-mdl/core` and the chip to provide tooltips.

You can check the full implementation of the fab-menu here: https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl-ext/tree/master/src/components/fab-menu

The main parts of the component are the templates of the menu and of the items

for the menu:

```html
<button mdl-button
    mdl-button-type="fab"
    mdl-colored="primary"
    (click)="fabPopover.toggle($event)"
    (touchstart)="alwaysShowTooltips = true"
>
  <mdl-icon>add</mdl-icon>
</button>
<mdl-popover #fabPopover [hide-on-click]="true" [class.direction-up]="true">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</mdl-popover>
```

and for the items:

```html
<button mdl-button mdl-button-type="mini-fab" (mouseover)="isHoovering = true" (mouseleave)="isHoovering = false" (click)="menuClick.emit()">
  <mdl-icon>{{icon}}</mdl-icon>
</button>
<mdl-chip [mdl-label]="label" [hidden]="!(fabMenu.alwaysShowTooltips || isHoovering)"></mdl-chip>
```

you can then use it like this:

```html
<mdl-fab-menu #mainFabMenu>
    <mdl-fab-menu-item
        [fabMenu]="mainFabMenu"
        icon="note_add"
        label="make a note"
        (menu-clicked)="log('we need to do something here')">
    </mdl-fab-menu-item>
    <mdl-fab-menu-item
        [fabMenu]="mainFabMenu"
        icon="refresh"
        label="refresh"
        (menu-clicked)="/*do something here*/">
    </mdl-fab-menu-item>
    <mdl-fab-menu-item
        [fabMenu]="mainFabMenu"
        icon="refresh"
        label="refresh"
        (menu-clicked)="/*do something here*/">
    </mdl-fab-menu-item>
</mdl-fab-menu>
```

check out here for the installation and the usage details: [@angular-mdl/fab-menu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-mdl/fab-menu)